# Check if object haves any nested objects and get its value

Tags: javascript, node-red

I have a sequence of JSON objects coming from a post request

```
{
  "labels": {
     "name": "Toma/Dyrskuvegen5/360.001/Avkasttemperatur"
  }
}
```

In some sequences the labels are empty (in which case should return false), in some, they are not.
Also in some sequences the

> labels.name

will be some other random key name, for example:

> labels.room_number

My task is to identify if there is any key under **labels** and set two strings, one with the key name, and the other with the key-value
example from above:

`n = "name"`

`v = "Toma/Dyrskuvegen5/360.001/Avkasttemperatur"`

Comment: How is `node-red` relevant to your question? Is there a limitation given by `node-red` that result in problems for what you have tried?

Comment: node-red is based on JavaScript (nodejs) there isn't any limitations so far i just lost my patience and decided to ask a question 

Comment: But you haven't shown us what you've tried, so we can't help you fix it. Stack Overflow will not just supply code based on requirements without seeing how you have already tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to do this. It returns an array of a given object's [key, value] pairs

```js
let incoming = {"labels":
    {"name":
    "Toma/Dyrskuvegen5/360.001/Avkasttemperatur"}};
    let incoming2 = {"labels":
    {"age":
    "22"}};
     let incoming3 = {"labels":
    {}};
    
let getThis = (incoming) => {
  let entries = Object.entries(incoming.labels);
  if(entries.length > 0){
  [s,v] = Object.entries(incoming.labels)[0];
  console.log(s,v);
  }
  return false;
};
getThis(incoming3);
getThis(incoming);
getThis(incoming2);
```

Comment: this is okay, assuming we have something under labels. but if data return haves empty labels it will throw a TypeError

Comment: No it wont. Check the snippet

Comment: Sorry, my bad I was deleting the entire .labels object when testing , that's why I was getting the answer( added a simple in/else for checking if my result .hasOwnProperty('labels') ) and it works great now. Thanks a lot